# Pantalla en gris con Leaflet 1.3.1

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet

Estoy utilizando Leaflet 1.3.1, para mostrar un mapa en un blog hecho con Laravel y Vue.js

Pero la pantalla aparece en grís. Aunque los markers, y los controles si aparecen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando pincho sobre Inspect Elements, y me voy a la capa , veo que me carga los .png del mapa del mundo. O sea, pinchando sobre ellos me muistra el Tile o Png de ese cuadrado en concreto del mapa.

Este es mi código:

**layout/app.blade.php**

```
  ..../
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="js/map/Leaflet.CountrySelect.js"></script>
/.....
```

**Home.blade.php**

```
  extends('layouts.app')
  @section('content')
  <style>
    .leatfet-container img{
      min-height: none;
      min-width:none;
   }

    </style>


    <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:700px"></div>
    <script>    
    var baseLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{attribution: 'Tiles &copy; CartoDB'});
    var map = L.map("map",{layers: [baseLayer], trackResize: false, center: [0.00, 0.00], zoom: 4});

    var select = L.countrySelect({exclude:"French Southern and Antarctic Lands"});

    select.addTo(map);

    select.on('change', function(e){
        if (e.feature === undefined){ //Do nothing on title
            return;
        }
            var country = L.geoJson(e.feature);
            if (this.previousCountry != null){
                map.removeLayer(this.previousCountry);
            }
            this.previousCountry = country;

            map.addLayer(country);
            map.fitBounds(country.getBounds());

        });
</script>

@foreach($articles as $article) 
<script>
var ltd = {{$article->longitude}};
var lng = {{$article->latitude}};

L.marker([ltd, lng]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("{{ $article->title }}").openPopup();
</script>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución. Creo. Cuando tu usas Vue.js no puedes usar  dentro de #map. Tengo que usar map de la manera de este ejemplo.

```
 new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
   map: null,
   tileLayer: null,
   layers: [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Restaurants',
    active: false,
    features: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Bogart\'s Smokehouse',
        type: 'marker',
        coords: [38.6109607, -90.2050322],
      },

  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'City/County Boundaries',
    active: false,
    features: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'City of St. Louis',
        type: 'polygon',
        coords: [
          [38.770547, -90.168056],

        ],
      },
      },
    ],
  }
],
 },
 mounted() {
  this.initMap();
  this.initLayers();
  },
  methods: {
layerChanged(layerId, active) {
  const layer = this.layers.find(layer => layer.id === layerId);

  layer.features.forEach((feature) => {
    if (active) {
      feature.leafletObject.addTo(this.map);
    } else {
      feature.leafletObject.removeFrom(this.map);
    }
  });
},
initLayers() {
  this.layers.forEach((layer) => {
    const markerFeatures = layer.features.filter(feature => feature.type     === 'marker');
    const polygonFeatures = layer.features.filter(feature => feature.type === 'polygon');

    markerFeatures.forEach((feature) => {
      feature.leafletObject = L.marker(feature.coords)
        .bindPopup(feature.name);
    });

    polygonFeatures.forEach((feature) => {
      feature.leafletObject = L.polygon(feature.coords)
        .bindPopup(feature.name);
    });
  });
},
initMap() {
  this.map = L.map('map').setView([38.63, -90.23], 12);
  this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer(
    'https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>',
    }
  );

  this.tileLayer.addTo(this.map);
},
 },
});
```